# Add image to acrofield in iText?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, acrofields

I'm trying to fill PDF using acrofields, I'm able to add string data perfectly, but having issues in adding images to acrofields. 
This is my code for adding string data..

```
    File f = new File("F:/Test/Agreement.pdf");
    InputStream sourceTemplatePDFUrlStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
    File destinationFile = new File("F:/Test/ag1.pdf");

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sourceTemplatePDFUrlStream);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(
            destinationFile));

    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    Image img = Image.getInstance("E:/signature/signature.png");
    Set fields = form.getFields().keySet();

    Hashtable val = new Hashtable();
    val.put("name", "xxx" );
    val.put("city_street_zip", "xxx"+"                    "+"xxx"+"                "+"xxx");
    val.put("chck_1", "Yes" );
    val.put("chck_2", "No");
    val.put("chck_3", "Yes" );
    val.put("street_address", "xxx" );
    val.put("account_num", "1234");



    Enumeration enumeration = val.keys();

    // iterate through Hashtable val keys Enumeration
    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
        String nextElement = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
        String nextElementValue = (String) val.get(nextElement);
        //System.out.println(nextElement + ":=================fillData===================:" + nextElementValue);
        form.setField(nextElement, nextElementValue);
    }

    //Form flattening makes the form non-editable and saveable with the 
    //form val filled in
    stamper.setFormFlattening(true);

    stamper.close();
```

Comment: @VigneshVino edited my question..included code

Comment: your stack trace will help me to understand u'r issue

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The "official" way to do this, is to have a Button field as placeholder for the image, and to replace the "icon" of the button as described in [my book](http://itextpdf.com/book):

```
PushbuttonField ad = form.getNewPushbuttonFromField(imageFieldName);
ad.setLayout(PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_ONLY);
ad.setProportionalIcon(true);
ad.setImage(Image.getInstance("E:/signature/signature.png"));
form.replacePushbuttonField("advertisement", ad.getField());
```

See [ReplaceIcon.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=156) for the full code sample.

DISCLAIMER: I'm the original developer of iText and the author of the "iText in Action" books.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! It's very nice to get reply from you :)

Comment: I like the concept of StackOverflow. That's why I joined last year. I try answering a couple of questions a day (although I don't always have the time).

Comment: form.getNewPushbuttonFromField(imageFieldName) return null for me

Answer (score 5):

The following solution worked:

```
public static void addImage(PdfStamper stamper,AcroFields form,String field,String fieldValue){
    try{
        System.out.println("Field "+field);
    java.util.List<AcroFields.FieldPosition> photograph = form.getFieldPositions(field);
    if(photograph!=null && photograph.size()>0){
    Rectangle rect= photograph.get(0).position;
    //if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(fieldValue)){
    Image img = Image.getInstance(fieldValue);
    img.scaleToFit(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
    img.setBorder(2);
    img.setAbsolutePosition(
    photograph.get(0).position.getLeft() + (rect.getWidth() - img.getScaledWidth() )
    , photograph.get(0).position.getTop() - (rect.getHeight()));
    PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent((int)photograph.get(0).page);
    cb.addImage(img);
    //}
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

calling the above method:

```
addImage(stamper, form, "CustomerSign", "E:/signature/signature.png");
```

where CustomerSign is AcroField

Answer (score 0):

You can try add this with your code for adding Image

```
PdfContentByte content = stamper.getOverContent(reader.getNumberOfPages());
Image image = Image.getInstance(new URL("E:/signature/signature.png"));
image.setAbsolutePosition(450,650);
image.scaleAbsolute(200,200);
content.addImage(image);
reader.close();
return output.toByteArray();
```