# Itextsharp: Using pushbuttons to fill images

Tags: asp.net, itext

As suggested by  Mr Bruno Lowagie [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052047/add-image-to-acrofield-in-itext/16056852#16056852), I've been using the push button field to fill images in custom templates, as such:

```
AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;
PushbuttonField logo = form.GetNewPushbuttonFromField("1");
if(logo != null)
{
     logo.Layout = PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_ONLY;
     logo.ProportionalIcon = true;
     logo.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Image.jpg"));
     form.ReplacePushbuttonField("1", logo.Field);
}
```

The problem is if I have multiple pushbuttons with field names 1, and I want to replace all of them with that same image, this only replaces the first one.

These are the push button fields before replacing their icon:

[image]

This is after I try to replace them, and only the first gets replaced:

[image]

I also saw that we can set `form.GetNewPushbuttonFromField(string field, int order)`, where order should be the index of the field with that field name?

So for testing I tried:

```
PushbuttonField logo = form.GetNewPushbuttonFromField("1", 0);
if(logo != null)
{
    logo.Layout = PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_ONLY;
    logo.ProportionalIcon = true;
    logo.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Image.jpg"));
    form.ReplacePushbuttonField("1", logo.Field);
}

PushbuttonField logo2 = form.GetNewPushbuttonFromField("1", 1);
if (CDlogo2 != null)
{
    logo2.Layout = PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_ONLY;
    logo2.ProportionalIcon = true;
    logo2.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Image.jpg"));
    form.ReplacePushbuttonField("1", logo2.Field);
}
```

However, for some reason the first pushbutton icon does not change and gets placed in the location of the second pushbutton that gets its icon changed, as such:

[image]

I need to be able to list through all of the pushbutton fields with that name field and replace all of them with that same image, how would I do that?

Thank you,

**EDIT**

As requested [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LEo9ZqjHq6ZhqEbRxMjn1RiqLiFDUwMP) is a link to view the pdfs

**EDIT 2**

If anyone cares this is how I'm using mkl's answer to loop and fill all images: (I know it's done terribly, but it works, yes, I'm keeping it for the time being)

```
int n= 0;
PushbuttonField logo = form.GetNewPushbuttonFromField("1", n);
while (logo != null)
{
    n++;
    logo = form.GetNewPushbuttonFromField("1", n);
}

PushbuttonField logo2;
for (int z = 0; z < n; z++)
{
    logo2 = form.GetNewPushbuttonFromField("1", z);
    logo2.Layout = PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_ONLY;
    logo2.ProportionalIcon = true;
    logo2.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath(imagePath));
    form.ReplacePushbuttonField("1", logo2.Field, z);
}
```

Because I couldn't find a method to get the number of pushbuttons with the same name.

Comment: Please share an example pdf that illustrates the issue.

Comment: @Federico Navarrete Hello, Im unsure how I can attach a pdf in stack overflow, the images are actual screenshots of the pdf that are being created. The big "1" are pushbutton fields with names 1.

Comment: What about a google drive file or upload it to a cloud?

Comment: I uploaded them to google drive and added the link in the post, thank you for your time @FedericoNavarrete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You

> saw that we can set `form.GetNewPushbuttonFromField(string field, int order)`, where order should be the index of the field with that field name

which is the correct direction to look. But you still used the `form.ReplacePushbuttonField` overload without an `order` parameter:

```
PushbuttonField logo2 = form.GetNewPushbuttonFromField("1", 1);
...
form.ReplacePushbuttonField("1", logo2.Field);
```

This creates a `PushbuttonField` from the second form field named "1" (including the position of the second button) and uses its information to replace the first field named "1". Thus, it

> gets placed in the location of the second pushbutton

So, to fix this you also have to use the `form.ReplacePushbuttonField` overload with an `order` parameter, if you use the `form.GetNewPushbuttonFromField` overload with an `order` parameter, and the values should match:

```
PushbuttonField logo2 = form.GetNewPushbuttonFromField("1", 1);
...
form.ReplacePushbuttonField("1", logo2.Field, 1);
```